# Spaces at the end of a code line messes up formatting

Tags: bug, status-norepro, code-formatting

If you have spaces at the end of code lines, then it doesn't indent properly ... sometimes.

The following has spaces at the end of the line, <s>and doesn't indent properly</s>

```
pagerange = 1..6
proxy = Net::HTTP::Proxy(proxy, port, user, pwd)
proxy.start('www.hirethings.co.nz') do |http|
  pagerange.each do |page|
    resp, data = http.get "/perth_dotnet?page=#{page}" 
    if resp.class == Net::HTTPOK
      (Hpricot(data)/"h3 a").each { |a| puts a.innerText }
    end
  end
end
```

Whereas the following doesn't have spaces at the end of the line, and therefore indents properly.

```
pagerange = 1..6
proxy = Net::HTTP::Proxy(proxy, port, user, pwd)
proxy.start('www.hirethings.co.nz') do |http|
  pagerange.each do |page|
    resp, data = http.get "/perth_dotnet?page=#{page}"
    if resp.class == Net::HTTPOK
      (Hpricot(data)/"h3 a").each { |a| puts a.innerText }
    end
  end
end
```

**Edit**: Reproduction fail! Um, look at a Google cache for [Options for HTML scraping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping)

Comment: Uh... none of the revisions look messed up to me http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3115/revisions

Comment: @Yi Jiang: No they don't, but have you looked at the google cache version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to very old posts remember that MarkdownSharp didn't exist then so there were old bugs possible.